# Sublime text 3 automatically highlights the texts when typing on mac

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, highlight

when i type something in sublime 3 it has a white box appear around the text, when i out focus the sublime and get focus back, the text which is highlighted disappear.

So i have to press escape or space to turn it off before saving which is super annoying. Tried to turn off some highlight functions in sublime setting but doesn't work.

please see the example image below, thanks

p/s i dont install any plugin except package control, and it happens to every language (php, js, html, text, xml ...)

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the plugins you have installed. Also, is this just in HTML, or do you see it in other languages/syntaxes? Is it just the word `text`, or are other words highlighted as well?

Comment: it highlights every word and any language i typed in.
it doesn't highlight the word "Html" because "Html text" is separated by the space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used a vietnamese keyboard, so turn it off when the problem sold.
i think it may happen to another keyboard. thanks